# How to count method callings in assembly?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a class with just one method:

```cs
public class EventPublisher
{
    public Task PublishAsync<T>(string title, T payload) { ... }
}
```

There are a few places in the code (in one assembly) I use it. Something like:

```cs
_publisher.PublishAsync("user-created", userCreatedEvent);
```

Is it possible to count once somehow (preferably after build, before deploy) - how many times I called it in my assembly and which parameters I used for? I assume to get in the end something like this:

```
{
  "in-assembly-calls" : [
    "user-created",
    "user-deleted",
    "user-updated"
  ]
}
```

P.S. I explain. There is a code in production we can't rewrite now. But we need to expose somehow all events which current code publishes. We definitely can do it manually but if somebody missed to append the docs after fixing code - it will ruin something.

Comment: If you can not modify it, just wrap it into something you can modify. Latest when you try to use the type, VS will complain about "no such Function/Property in that type".

Comment: We use JetBrains Rider on Linux :) by the way, it's a really good idea to wrap it with something, but first of all my goal is to expose all events out of the app, so I can get which events current service send.. sorry, maybe I miss-understood something?

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you are trying to replace a class you can not modify with something self made. And to know where to start you want to figure out wich Functions and Events are *actually* called by your rather large codebase - so you do not implement unused stuff. Ideally even splitting it up between different Function overloads and counting wich ones are used the most.

I do not know of any way to do that kind of counting or code analysis. The best I can think off is having the Compiler complain about missing pieces.

There are only a few ways I can think off:

1. Just replace the instance. Follow all "Type X does not contain the definition of Method Y" Compiler errors.
2. You wrap the existing class into something you wrote yourself. Go to step 1 and figure out wich functions need to be reachable. At the start, all you do is relay calls to the contained instance. That keeps the coding need to a minimum. Later you can make a alternative Implementation using this same class.
3. You use "Extract Interface" or "Extract Abstract class" on the exisiting thing. You create a class that implements it. The default implementation is `throw new NotImplementedException();` You just test the whole thing and follow the Exceptions.

As for the design, I like to use a small class Heirarchy and a static or instance variable for this:

```
class abstract Accessor{ }

class oldImplementation : Acessor {}

class newImplementation : Acessor {}
```

And then in code something like this:

```
static Acessor AcessProvider = new oldImplementation();
//or
static Acessor AcessProvider = new newImplementation();
```

However based on the Functions in your example, this sounds suspiciously like a Database Access code. Make sure not to accidentally create any Global instances that keep in memory without being Disposed. You can try to use Aliases for quick replacement:

```
using AcessProviderType = oldAcessType;
```

But you have to first change all code using the old thing directly to the Alias, of course. Here you can just comment out the using or even remove the reference to figure out wich places you missed.